# sql query help me with correct update statement

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-adf

I have table name `emp` with 3 columns `empid`, `datof birth`, `doj`

There is an another table `test`, it has 2 columns `empid` `date of birth`. The employee id is the same in both tables.

My requirement is in emp table for some employees in dateofbirth (dob) column who is haveing date '01/05/2011' has to be updated by the dob in table 2 (test)

I need a update statement.

I have joined the query I got some records now I need to replace employees dob in table1 with date  dob of same employee  from table 2 (test)

Comment: Show your JOIN query...

Comment: How many times do you want this answered? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16505612/update-query-resulting-wrongly/16505716#16505716

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle does not support `JOIN` query directly with `UPDATE` Statement...

A workaround would be like this:

```
UPDATE 
  (SELECT emp.dob AS emp_dob, test.dob AS test_dob
 FROM emp 
 INNER JOIN test
 ON emp.empid  = test.empid 
) tbl
SET tbl.emp_dob = tbl.test_dob
```

Comment: Sorry Bro it is not working ...it throwing an error....................ORA-01779: cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table

Comment: Is empid unique? If not, Please add unique constraint on that so it would ensures that there will be no ambiguous row....

Comment: Make empid of test table(table2) unique...